# How to find sum from 1 to 1 million in C?

Tags: c

How to find sum from 1 to 1 million in C?  I tried using unsigned long long data type(my code below) but that prints `500,000,000,000`. Correct value is `500,000,500,000`.

```
unsigned long long sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    sum += (unsigned long long)i;
printf("%llu",sum);
```

Comment: Why cast i every iteration? Why not just make i the expected type from the get-go? And you want the end condition to use `<=` if you want to include 1000000.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression Use a closed formula, no need to iterate so many times. In this case, (1 + 1000000)*1000000/2

Comment: `for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < 1000001; i++)` should leave you with the correct result. What you are doing is adding the sum of 0 to 999,999 I believe.

Comment: Your code should _actually_ result in `499,999,500,000`. You should probably check your CPU if you are getting `500,000,000,000`

Comment: The sum of `1..N` is always equal to `N / 2 * (N + 1)`.

Comment: @4castle Well, if we want to optimize it we can just do `printf("500000500000");`...

Comment: Maybe the OP is just trying to do it the long (no pun intended) way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The updated code also shows wrong answer. But I tried running on ideone, it gave the right answer. My CPU must have a problem. @Matt, could you guide me to some article/question which helps me solve this.

Comment: @DhruvRatanGupta: first: are you sure you posted the exact same code here as you compiled and ran on both your machine and ideone?  If so, let us know exactly what platform (including x86 or x64) you are running on and what compiler toolchain & version you're using.

Comment: 'My CPU must have a problem' well, possibly.  Mr. Occam says that it's overwhelmingly more likely that you are running the old version by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This should leave you with the correct answer. In your example you were finding the sum of 0 to 999,999. I also removed the needless casting for you.

```
unsigned long long sum = 0;

for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) sum += i;

printf("%llu", sum);
```

Comment: The  coding "contract" was "1 to 1 million".  Better to use those constants in code that make up magic numbers `1000001.

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency of the naive approach is terrible ! You should use the property that the sum of the integers from 0 to n is n(n+1)/2.

Answer (score 1):

You sum up all numbers from 0 to 999999. Your result is some Kinde of strange.

With this you should get the correct one:

```
unsigned long long sum=0;
for(unsigned long long i=1;i<=1000000;i++){
    sum+=i;
}
```

Comment: should be `i < 1000001`

Comment: No problem Evan! Our solutions are equivalent.